# Changing Database from SQLServer to Mysql in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have done my project using **ASP.Net MVC** and **SQL SERVER** but the website which i gonna host, is not supporting SQL SERVER they asked me to change my database to **MYSQL**.

I used many ways, but got different run time errors.

QUESTION: HOW CAN I CHANGE MY DATABASE FROM SQL SERVER TO MYSQL?

**Here is my model and context model:**

```
namespace WebApplication11.Models
{
    [Table("Product")]
    public class ProductModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please provide Product id",AllowEmptyStrings =false)]
        public int pid { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Product Name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter the Price", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Specify the Product Category", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
        public string ProductAddress { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage1 { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage2 { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage3 { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Customer ID", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
       // public DateTime ProductSubTime { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Customer")]
    public class CustomerModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int cid { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Customer name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string CustomerFullName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Contact Number", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public int CustomerContact { get; set; }
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Gender", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string CustomerGender { get; set; }
        public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    }


    [Table("adminlogin")]
    public class adminlogin
    {
        [Key]

        public string id { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Specify your name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string pass { get; set; }
        public string designation { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("contact")]
    public class contact
    {
        [Key]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Specify your name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your contact", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string phone { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Specify Email", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter sugestion ", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Category")]
    public class itemcategory
    {
        [Key]
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

    }

    public class ContextModel :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CustomerModel> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<itemcategory> itemCat { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication11.Models.adminlogin> adminlogins { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication11.Models.contact> contacts { get; set; }
    }
```

**My connection string**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ContextModel" 
         connectionString="Data Source=noori\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=salesWebsiteDB;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**And my homepage controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()

{
    var bike = cm.Products.Where(p => p.ProductCategory == "Bike").ToList();
    var mobile = cm.Products.Where(p => p.ProductCategory == "Mobile").ToList();
    var others = cm.Products.Where(p => p.ProductCategory != "Cars" && p.ProductCategory!= "Mobile").ToList();

    ViewBag.bike = bike.ToList();
    ViewBag.mobile = mobile.ToList();
   ViewBag.others = others.ToList();


    return View(cm.Products.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Posting those error messages would go a long way in helping us know what you need to do.

Comment: Thnks for replying, I tried different ways, i was almost concentrating on **Connection string ** like changing the _server name, data source , name_ and other attributes in connection string, by changing any of them i got different errors like_ server does not support data source , entity problem , cant reach to database_ and many kind of errors. if you will can you please try the code by your own. even just for one model and controller and figure it out.

Comment: You might be better off finding another host.

Comment: I agree with @Dan that a different host is likely the easiest solution. But if you want to change your connection strings you can't just change a piece or two. Each DBMS has some specific requirements for how to form a connection string. For those details you can go here. https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I already bought a host and domain name in [Godady.com](http://godady.com) , there while creating a new database i dont have SQL SERVER option only MYSQL is there.@DanBracuk @Sean Lange

Comment: If you want to change database engines, you are going to have to worry about more than connection strings.  All your table designs and queries will have to be re-tested.

Comment: Thnks my problem with [godady.com] has been solved i upgraded my account and now i have MSSQL type also for my database, but dont know how to host can you please guide me, how to host ?

Comment: NO. We can't help you with hosting at godaddy. They have tutorials on their site for this. You are paying them, utilize the help you are paying for.

Comment: Thnks @SeanLange, I will approach them..